# If we are traveling to Mars in Hibernation State

Tags: space-travel

If we are traveling to Mars in Hibernation State with artificial gravity. Which hibernation position of our body is the best i.e. lie flat or stand up, considering making bone loss as less as possible.

Comment: Flat or laying down with regard to which gravity? Or lets ask it another way: How would you define 'down' in space?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about human biology. Also, humans don't "hibernate" and there is no evidence that human could be made to "hibernate" safely for months.

Answer (score 1):

Bone remodels in response to stress in order to maintain constant strain energy per bone mass throughout. To do this, it grows more dense in areas experiencing high stress, while resorbing density in areas experiencing low stress. Thus, a vertical position (vertical as defined by the direction of the artificial gravity will be better for some bones that are aligned with it (such as those on arms, legs and spine) but not much different for ribs, the skull, and other bones. The best method could be rotating the bodies randomly and continuously.